# read known file extensions / types from the registry

Tags: windows, delphi, registry

I want to present the user with a list of known file extensions for him to pick. I know that these are stored in the Registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT usually like this:

.txt -> (default)="txtfile"

where txtfile then contains the information about associated programs etc.

Unfortunately that place in the registry also stores lots of other keys, like the file types (e.g. txtfile) and entries like

CAPICOM.Certificates (whatever that is)

How do I determine which of the entries are file extensions? Or is there a different way to get these extensions like an API function?

(I don't think it matters, but I am using Delphi for the program.)

Comment: Just in case anybody is interested, this is what I eventually wrote: http://sourceforge.net/p/dzlib/code/125/tree/dzlib/trunk/src/u_dzFileTypes.pas Be warned that it is at this time mostly untested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that every keys preceded by a dot in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is intended for file association, but every file association requires creation of a key preceded by a dot. See MSDN on [File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144148(VS.85).aspx#fa_register_type) topic.

AFAIK, the method I describe here conforms with how the Windows *Set File Associations* feature works to get a list of all known file types. It was based on my former observation when I delved into this subject.

To achieve that, you'll need to do intricate steps as follows:

1. Enumerating every keys preceded by a dot `.` , you can use RegQueryInfoKey() and RegEnumKeyEx() for this purpose.
2. In every keys preceded by a dot, look at the default value data:

   **a.** If the default value is **not empty**, *this is enough indication that the "preceding dot key" is intended for file association in all Windows NT version*, then try to open the key name as mentioned by the value data, just says *TheKeyNameMentioned*.

   **a1)** If **there is** subkeys `shell\open\command` under *TheKeyNameMentioned*, then test the existence of the path pointed by the default value of this key; if the path exists, there is a default application associated with the extension; if the path doesn't exists, the default application is unknown. To get the file extension description, look at the default value of *TheKeyNameMentioned*. To get the program description, first, test whether the following key contain a value-name equal to the EXE file path, that is `HKCR\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache`. If it is there, then look at the value data to get the file description; if it is not there, use GetFileVersionInfo() directly to get the file description.

   **a2)** If **there is no** subkeys `shell\open\command` under *TheKeyNameMentioned*, then the default application is unknown. To get the file extension description, look at the default value of *TheKeyNameMentioned*.

   **b.** On Windows Vista and later, when the point **[a]** fails, you need additional check. If the default value is **empty**, test whether the key has a subkey named `OpenWithProgIDs`.

   - If `OpenWithProgIDs` subkey **exists**, use RegEnumValue() to find the first encountered value name that meets the criteria, that is, the *name* of the value name must point to an existing key (just says *TheKeyNameMentioned*.) with the same name as the value name. If *TheKeyNameMentioned* exists, *this is enough indication that the "preceding dot key" is intended for file association*. Read point **a1** and **a2** for the next steps.
   - If `OpenWithProgIDs` subkey **doesn't exist**, the default application is unknown. To get the file extension description, look at the default value of *TheKeyNameMentioned*.

Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Don't rely on looking at just the `shell\open\command` subkey. Any custom verb name can be registered underneath the `shell` key, not just `open`, and not all verbs use the `command` subkey, some use the `ddeexec` or `DropTarget` subkey instead.

Comment: There seems to be another option: If the default value of TheKeyNameMentioned is empty, there can be a FriendlyTypeName value which contains the type name. And even worse, this type name can point to a resource string. See the entry of PerfFile (.pma) for an example. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374120(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

For a command-line alternative, the [assoc](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/assoc.mspx?mfr=true) command-line program included in Windows shows registered file extensions.

```
c:\> assoc
.3g2=VLC.3g2
.3gp=VLC.3gp
.3gp2=VLC.3gp2
.3gpp=VLC.3gpp
...
```

I'm not sure which verb this looks for. `Open` perhaps? I'm also not sure which extensions will appear in this list. Perhaps the extensions of files that can open from the command line.

To then find out which executable is mapped to each file type, the [ftype](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftype.mspx?mfr=true) command will tell:

```
c:\> ftype VLC.3g2
VLC.3g2="c:\vlc.exe" --started-from-file "%1"
```

Comment: Learned something new today... For those who wonder: This command already exists in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO - all those registry subkeys starting with the dot (`.`) - are for file extensions.

For instance in your case `.txt` stands for the "txt" extension, whereas `txtfile` doesn't start with the dot.

Comment: Is that your guess (I guessed that as well) or is it documented somewhere? I found documentation for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in MSDN but it did not clarify which entries are extensions and which are not.

Comment: This is my "scientific guess". I tried to add a new subkey under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT starting with dot. Then added the corresponding stuff, and finally called 'SHChangeNotify'. And - voila! this worked!

Comment: My impression is that "txtfile" is a level of indirection. You can have e.g. "txtfile" and several dot-style entries pointing to it, e.g. ".txt", ".ini", ".csv" which then all point to "txtfile" where the shared settings are stored.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details, but it seems you could use the [IQueryAssociations interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761400%28VS.85%29.aspx).