# .NET - How to get all video formats instead of specifying each format

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to get all document formats instead of specifying explicitly (ie -> .pdf, .doc etc) ?

Similarly, how do I get all video formats instead of specifying explicitly all video formats?

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

ofd.filter = "DOCUMENT|*.pdf";  //filter document without giving all formats explicitly.
```

Comment: `ofd.filter`? or `ofd.Filter`?

Comment: What do you mean by `etc` when you say `.pdf, .doc etc`?  Computers need to be told exactly what to do.

Comment: Couldn't you simply look at the example in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2): `dlg.Filter = "Word Documents|*.doc|Excel Worksheets|*.xls|PowerPoint Presentations|*.ppt|Office Files|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt|All Files|*.*";` and adapt it?

Comment: @Wyck There are over 30 image formats. I think it won't be efficient to type all formats. Instead, there should be some way I could specify all formats (say "image/*")

Comment: "All formats" surely depends on what your program will/can process, no? Since you seem a beginner, stick with a string (or string list/array) for the formats supported by your program. That should work for now. When you get more proficient in C#, you will definitely be able to choose an approach that is more flexible/dynamic (= more complex), like having some data structure that keeps track of all supported formats (and where the handlers/consumers of each particular format would be registered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter mechanism works by **file extension** only. You can list multiple extensions per group and break the list into multiple groups like this:

```
.Filter = "Video Files (*.avi, *.mp4)|*.avi;*.mp4|Document Files (*.pdf, *.doc, *.docx, *.txt)|*.pdf;*.doc;*.docx;*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
```

But this will always require you to be explicit about the exact list of file extensions you want to support.

You can construct the Filter definition string programmatically, so if you're hoping to somehow locate all files with the same *class* (according to the shell) or *mime type*, then you'll have to create a filter from some authoritative source of your choosing. 
 Possibly either by [probing the system registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849560/read-known-file-extensions-types-from-the-registry), or by using an [up-to-date mime type map](https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap).